# Order columns in a spreadsheet from a google docs form

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

you can't move columns in the table from side to side since doing so would disrupt the structure from the table. This is what google support and/or help pages say.

My problem is that if I create a form in google docs. And I accidentally create a question that I should have created earlier and then I move the question up the form. The column doesn't move in the spreadsheet.

So my form spreadsheet looks messed up now. Is there a way to fix this without typing all my questions(89) again. I don't have any results in the sheet yet. So I'm looking for a regenerate sheet option or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you move the questions around in the Form, the order in which the questions and answers appear in the so called Form Responses sheet remain the same as the one in which the Form questions were originally created.

You can, however, rearrange the questions_and_answers columns in the Form Responses sheet to match the order in which the questions appear in the Form (yes there will be a warning against doing it, but I have done it safely despite the warning) ... see my following blog post for an illustration ...
http://yogi--anand-consulting.blogspot.com/2011/11/yogimake-column-headers-and-answers_27.html

Comment: So what you saying is ignore the warning message?

Comment: I can confirm that form responses are recorded correctly after changing column order on the responses sheet. Just be sure you don't have any custom scripts that rely on column order.

Comment: At least 2 people could see that after this change, it does not record new data into the table.

Answer (score 18):

The simplest option is to unlink the form from the spreadsheet it is linked to and then relink it to the same spreadsheet. It will create a new sheet in that spreadsheet, but this time it will be in the good order.

You can then copy the old answers from the old sheet into your new sheet and rearrange them manually.

Comment: If you follow this answer and the spreadsheet is connected to a form that you manually embedded on another site, do not forgot to grab the new `name="entry.xxxxxxxx"` and insert it where you had earlier placed the name value.

Comment: This works really well. In the latest version of forms it brings over all of the existing data and put the columns in the right order.

Comment: Great solution, strikes me as more appropriate than the "accepted" one. I wasn't sure how to link/unlink so here are the steps from googling "Google Forms Link Spreadsheet": 

- Open a form in Google Forms.
- At the top, click RESPONSES.
- Below, click More ("...")
- Click Select response destination.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1.

If you don´t have a lot of checkboxes, etc, but just blank short answers, what about:

1. Make a copy (to test)
2. Delete form.
3. Move columns
4. Create form. (which will default to short blank answers for your questions.)

Solution 2.

1. Make a new sheet
2. Use an arrayformula to copy results from the first sheet, putting them where you want them.
3. hide the first sheet.

Comment: arrayformula? Is that like a VB macro in office?

Answer (score -1):

If you did not collect any answers yet, an easiest solution would be to copy the report.

Once you have the questions in the order you want, click `File>Make a Copy`.

The response sheet for this new report will be in the order of your questions.